# Asynchronous loading in an Ember Component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an autocomplete component within a form. Upon inserting the component, I run this function:

```
  setSearchInput: (->
    username = @get 'targetObject.user.username'
    @set('searchInput', username)
  ).on('didInsertElement')
```

The targetObject in this case is the form, which has access to the content model's associated `user`. At this point, the `user` might not yet be loaded. Typically, this would prompt Ember-Data to query the server and return a promise. However, in this case it does not return a promise. It returns undefined. However, it returns the expected result if I force Ember to pause a second like this:

```
  setSearchInput: (->
    window.setTimeout =>
      username = @get 'targetObject.content.user.username'
      @set('searchInput', username)
    , 1000
  ).on('didInsertElement')
```

I experience something similar if I set a breakpoint on `@set('searchInput', username)`. `username` will be undefined, but if I run `@get 'targetObject.content.user.username'` at this point, it will return the expected result.

Any idea what's going on? Ember-Data is still in beta, so perhaps this is a bug? Has anyone else encountered this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume user is a `belongsTo` async object here (if not you'll need to show what content is up there, cause I'm having to guess), and I'm going to do it in javascript (sorry, if I do it in coffeescript it will probably confuse you more ;) )

```
setSearchInput: function(){
  var self = this; 
  this.get('targetObject.user').then(function(user){
    self.set('searchInput', user.get('username'));
  });
}.on('didInsertElement')
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/691/edit

Comment: Thanks, that was the hint I needed. The relationship wasn't set to async: true. Once I did that, I could get it to return a promise as expected.